# How to inplace the result to the original dataframe in r tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to calculate the day difference by the number of row of groups:

```
v = data.frame(group = c('a','a','b','c','c'),days_difference = c(0,56,0,0,23))

v %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(n() == 1) %>% mutate(days_difference = (difftime(as.Date('01-01-2020', "%d-%m-%Y"),as.Date('04-06-2018',"%d-%m-%Y"))))
```

In the above code, if the length of groups is equal to one, then the `days_difference` will change from 0 to `difftime(as.Date('01-01-2020', "%d-%m-%Y"),as.Date('04-06-2018',"%d-%m-%Y"))`.

However, I need to use dummy variables in order to insert the result into the original data.frame.
Is there anyways to use `inplace` in r? Or how to use `ifelse` in mutate function?

Please give me some suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use base R's `ifelse`:

Usage: after `mutate` we set the new column name then `=` and then `ifelse()`. Within ifelse the arguments are: ifelse(condition, result if TRUE, result if FALSE). It is always this macro. In the condition term you can combine multiple conditions. Like in your case we check  `n() == 1` AND `days_difference == 0`. After doing the condition we set a coma. The next argument is what should happen if this condition is TRUE in your case  `difftime(as.Date('01-01-2020', "%d-%m-%Y"), as.Date('04-06-2018',"%d-%m-%Y"))` then we set again a coma and the last argument is what will happen if the condition is FALSE in your case (the values in `days_difference` column.

Type ?ifelse in your console and see the documentation.

```
library(dplyr)
v %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(
    days_difference = ifelse(n() == 1 & days_difference == 0,
                             difftime(as.Date('01-01-2020', "%d-%m-%Y"), as.Date('04-06-2018',"%d-%m-%Y")),
                             days_difference)
  )

  group days_difference
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 a                   0
2 a                  56
3 b                 576
4 c                   0
5 c                  23
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not familiar with using `ifelse` in mutate, would you mind to share more examples about this technique? Thank you!

Comment: Appreciate your explanation! I have one more question to ask: Is it possible to replace `difftime` with `diff`? Since I would like to calculate the lagged and iterated differences.

Comment: We could do it this way if we want to use diff: `v %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(
    days_difference = ifelse(n() == 1 & days_difference == 0,
                             diff(strptime(c('04-06-2018', '01-01-2020'), "%d-%m-%Y")),
                             days_difference)
  )`